# Split string in column and add value in column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with several rows of data like this :

```
16  W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\ALxO_Amendement #1_20091022_signed.pdf
17  W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\Level1\ALBO_Amendment #1_20110418.docx
18  W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\A\BR\T\X_#1_20110418_final.docx
19  W:\2-Work\ALBO\MyOptionl\AO_Amendment_2 August 2013.docx
```

I have created columns from `Col1` to `Col10`

I would like to separate each value with the delimiter `'\'`

The idea is to have on each column :

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |etc...

W:  2-Work  ALBO  00_Proposal ALxO_Amendement #1_20091022_signed.pdf
```

I know how to use `charindex` and `substring` but the number of '' are different on each line (8500 rows).

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

### Edit

My goal is to generate an XML of the full path and split path.

Actually, here is my idea :

1 - Identify all the ID in a temporary table to do loop

```
--On déclare une table tempo
declare @IdTable Table (
id int,
src nvarchar(max))

--On injecte tous les id existant de la table
insert into @IdTable (id, src)
select id, src from albo

--on déclare l'id de début en commencant par le plus petit
declare @id int = (select min(id) from ALBO)

--Tnat qu'il reste des ID on continue la boucle
while @id is not null
begin

print @id
select @id = min(id) from @IdTable where ID > @id
end
--Fin de la boucle des ID
```

2 - Split each row and update column (Colx => The Columns have been created before). This code should be placed into my previous loop.

```
Declare @products varchar(max) = 'W:\2-Work\ALBO\13_WP Reporting\13_07_Monthly reports\13_07_01 Archives\2012\201211\Draft\ALBO-MR-201211\gp_scripts\v1\Top10_duree_final.txt'
Declare @individual varchar(max) = null

WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%\%',@products) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@products, 0, PATINDEX('%\%',@products))
        select @individual --i have to make and update with the ID

        SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products, LEN(@individual + '\') + 1,
                                                     LEN(@products))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @products
        SET @products = NULL
        print @individual
    END
END
```

Comment: That is not a good table desgin. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can create a function to split the data by "\" and return a table for each row, then insert the table in you col1 to col10 with insert statement from you split function. Try writing your code to implement the above, incase you face the issue we are here! :)

Comment: Aren't you just replacing '\' with ' '?

Comment: I would like to 'explode' the row and update 'Col1' to 'Col10' with the value like for example : 'This\Is\My\Sentence' => Col1 : This | Col2 : Is | Col3 : My | Col4 : Sentence

Comment: What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve? Why do you think creating 10 arbitrary columns is the solution to this? (it isn't). If you are trying to gather statistics about folders, there are other ways to do it

Comment: Is this just a one off thing? You can do it with a recursive CTE that returns substrings, then PIVOTing the result

Comment: It would be much better to split them properly (in an application maybe?) and store it correctly, almost regardless of how you're going to use it.  But for this you'll have to make a function which splits an input (use while loop) and then run that on each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, this probably isn't the best way to do things, if you explain what you'll be doing with the results it might help us provide a better option

[Also, for some reason the colours of the code below are showing up odd, so copy and paste it into your Sql server to see it better]

```
drop table #Path

create table #Path (item bigint,location varchar(1000))

insert into #Path 
select 16  ,'W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\ALxO_Amendement #1_20091022_signed.pdf' union
select 17  ,'W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\Level1\ALBO_Amendment #1_20110418.docx' union
select 18  ,'W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\A\BR\T\X_#1_20110418_final.docx' union
select 19  ,'W:\2-Work\ALBO\MyOptionl\AO_Amendment_2 August 2013.docx'


select * from #Path;


with Path_Expanded(item,subitem,location, start, ending, split)
as(
select item
     , 1 --subitem begins at 1
     , location -- full location path
     , 0 --start searching the file from the 0 position
     , charindex('\',location) -- find the 1st '\' charactor
     , substring(location,0,charindex('\',location)) --return the string from the start position, 0, to the 1st '\' charactor

from #Path
union all
select item
     , subitem+1 --add 1 to subitem
     , location -- full location path
     , ending+1 -- start searching the file from the position after the last '\' charactor
     , charindex('\',location,ending+1)-- find the 1st '\' charactor that occurs after the last '\' charactor found
     , case when charindex('\',location,ending+1) = 0 then substring(location,ending+1,1000) --if you cant find anymore '\', return everything else after the last '\'
            else substring(location,ending+1, case when charindex('\',location,ending+1)-(ending+1) <= 0 then 0 
            else charindex('\',location,ending+1)-(ending+1) end )--returns the string between the last '\' charactor and the next '\' charactor
            end 

from Path_Expanded
where ending > 0 --stop once you can't find anymore '\' charactors
)


--pivots the results 
select item
    , max(case when subitem = 1 then split else '' end) as col1
    , max(case when subitem = 2 then split else '' end) as col2
    , max(case when subitem = 3 then split else '' end) as col3
    , max(case when subitem = 4 then split else '' end) as col4
    , max(case when subitem = 5 then split else '' end) as col5
    , max(case when subitem = 6 then split else '' end) as col6
    , max(case when subitem = 7 then split else '' end) as col7
    , max(case when subitem = 8 then split else '' end) as col8
    , max(case when subitem = 9 then split else '' end) as col9
    , max(case when subitem = 10 then split else '' end) as col10

from Path_Expanded
group by item
```

you might prefer to have each folder on its own row, if so replace the pivot part above with the below query instead

```
select  item
      , subitem
      , location
      , split from Path_Expanded where item = 16
```

Comment: My Goal is to create an XML width all the 'explose' information and keep the original path too.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will get what you are looking for; as others have noted, it's not a particularly good design.  For example, what happens when you're looking for the file name and it's in a different column each time?

Regardless, this will do what you asked for (and maybe even what you want):

```
-- Test Data
CREATE TABLE #FilePath (FileNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1), FilePath VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO #FilePath (FilePath) 
SELECT 'W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\ALxO_Amendement #1_20091022_signed.pdf' UNION
SELECT 'W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\Level1\ALBO_Amendment #1_20110418.docx' UNION
SELECT 'W:\2-Work\ALBO\00_Proposal\A\BR\T\X_#1_20110418_final.docx' UNION
SELECT 'W:\2-Work\ALBO\MyOptionl\AO_Amendment_2 August 2013.docx'
GO

-- Numbers CTE
WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE n+1 <= 1000 -- set this to the maximum length of your file path
)

SELECT 
    FilePath,
    [1] AS Col1,
    [2] AS Col2,
    [3] AS Col3,
    [4] AS Col4,
    [5] AS Col5,
    [6] AS Col6,
    [7] AS Col7,
    [8] AS Col8,
    [9] AS Col9,
    [10] AS Col10
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        FilePath, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FilePath ORDER BY n) RowNum,
        CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(NULLIF(SUBSTRING('\' + FilePath + '\' , n , CHARINDEX('\' ,     '\' + FilePath + '\' , n) - n) , ''))) AS VARCHAR(1000)) FolderName
    FROM Numbers, #FilePath
    WHERE 
        n <= Len('\' + FilePath + '\') AND SubString('\' + FilePath + '\' , n - 1, 1) = '\' AND 
        CharIndex('\' , '\' + FilePath+ '\' , n) - n > 0
  )P
PIVOT 
   (MAX(FolderName) FOR RowNum IN 
    ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
    ) UP
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)-- set this to the maximum length of your file path


-- Clean up
DROP TABLE #FilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (de-dupes):

```
;with T(ordinal, path, starts, pos) as (
    select 1, path, 1, charindex('\', path) from #tbl
    union all
    select ordinal + 1, path, pos + 1, charindex('\', path, pos + 1)
    from t where pos > 0
)
select [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10] from (
    select 
        ordinal, path, substring(path, starts, case when pos > 0 then pos - starts else len(path) end) token
    from T
) T2
pivot (max(token) for ordinal in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) T3
```