# SQL PATINDEX ParseString

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, parsing

Lets say I have data such as

```
/dogs/2013/mango/oh-40/8/
/cats/21/pineapple/de-11/24/ 
/sharks/234/banana/pl-33/123/
```

Can those be parsed with combination of `PATINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` by delimiter `"/"` and `"-"`? I am not sure whether I am able to use RegEx for such situation. What would be the solution? I cant think any of it.

Result:

```
dogs    2013    mango       oh    40      8
cats    21      pineapple   de    11      24
sharks  234     banana      pl    33      123
```

Comment: Google "SQL Server split string" and you will find the implementation of a function that can help you.

Comment: I was wondering whether it is possible to do it without UDF.

Comment: Is the number of tokens always 5 ?

Comment: It may vary, this is just example. However I want to understand the logic which can hopefully be applied to data with more tokens. Sometimes it may look like /sharks/banana/pl-33/123/545474fda with one column missing and other added. But I think thats much harder case that cannot be solved without UDF.

Comment: There is a solution with PIVOT (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24384064/246342) but it requires a known fixed or reasonable maximum number.  There are other solutions in the link.

Comment: @Dnac . . . In that case, google "sql server split string recursive CTE".  I think there might be an XML method as well.